# Clang/llvm: crt1.o crti.o not found while cross compilation

Tags: clang, cross-compiling, linaro

I am trying to cross compile a sample hello world program on ARM using clang/llvm.

i am facing some problem in linking.

**clang -target arm-none-linux-gnueabi hello.c**

It shows some error that "***no such file or directory "stdio.h***"

so to avoid the error i gave following command.

**clang -target arm-none-linux-gnueabi -sysroot=/path/toolchain/ hello.c -I/path/toolchain/sysroot/usr/include/**

Then i successfully over come the error, but i got the linking error.
error: "***no such file or directory crt1.o***"
       "***no such file or directory crti.o***"
i exported the library path and also gave the path in command line but nothing is working for me. i gave the following command.

**clang -target arm-none-linux-gnueabi -sysroot=/path/toolchain/ hello.c -I/path/toolchain/sysroot/usr/include/ -L/path/toolchain/sysroot/usr/lib**

still the same error
"***no such file or directory crt1.o***"
"***no such file or directory crti.o***"

Looking forward for any help.
i was using clang-3.0, later i downloaded the prebuilt binaries and upgraded to clang-3.3.
Thanks in advance.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above question can be solved by the following command.

```
clang -target armv7-none-eabi -sysroot=/toolchain/path/to/sysroot/ hello.c -ccc-gcc-name arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc hello.c
```

Here target says the clang compiler to choose proper target. sysroot says the exact path to take the headers and libraries(No need to provide include and library paths)

Comment: I wish you had included details on what that actually does under the hood.